# Can a block enable loading of css/js?

Tags: javascript, wagtail

I want to create a block that is going to utlize some js/css from a CDN, and possibly some custom js code just before the `</body>`. I do not want these loaded unless the block is used on the current page. Is there a way I can check if the block has been used, or even better, have the block tell the `base.html` file that it is being used?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have jQuery in your project, the easiest way to do this will be with `getScript`. Documentation is here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

With plain JS, you have to jump through slightly more hoops and create a `<script>` tag that you then append to the document:

```
var dynamically_loaded_js = document.createElement('script');
dynamically_loaded_js.setAttribute('src','http://example.com/dynamically_loaded.js');
document.body.appendChild(dynamically_loaded_js);
```

Comment: That could possibly solve the custom code issue. Thanks for the input.